# Dask inconsistent behavior when column order differs between meta and individual DataFrames

Tags: dask

I'm building a dataframe from `delayed` objects which returns individual (pandas) dataframes and I provide the `meta` to the `from_delayed` call.

It happened that the column order returned by the delayed objects didn't match the one provided in the `meta`.

In that case, dask would get confused and mix up the data between the two ordering depending on the computation asked.

e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask import delayed

source = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['(1)', '(2)', 'date', 'ent', 'val'],
    data=[range(i*5, i*5+5) for i in range(3)],
    index=range(3)
)

# Note the meta doesn't have the same ordering for columns
meta = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['date', 'ent', 'val', '(1)', '(2)'],
    data=[range(5)]
)

# This works
ddf = dd.from_delayed([delayed(lambda: source)()], meta=meta)

# one result
ddf.compute()    
# (1) | (2) | date | ent | val
# --- | --- | ---- | --- | ---
#  0  |  1  |  2   |  3  |  4
#  5  |  6  |  7   |  8  |  9
# 10  | 11  | 12   | 13  | 14

# a very different one
ddf.reset_index().compute()
# index | date | ent | val | (1) | (2)
# ----- | ---- | --- | --- | --- | ---
#    0  |   0  |  1  |  2  |  0  |  0
#    1  |   5  |  6  |  7  | 10  |  5
#    2  |  10  | 11  | 12  | 20  | 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proposed by @mdurant, the ordering can be forced:

```
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: x[['date', 'ent', 'val', '(1)', '(2)']])
```

on the result of `from_delayed`.

That can also be done at the function called by the `delayed` object if that function has access to the ordering.

Comment: It would be good to accept your answer, so it shows up green in searches.

Comment: I will but need to wait two days